# document.getqueryselector and getelement by class not working

Tags: javascript, html

I have checked other questions and they have helped a bit.

But for me it's still not showing much success:

```
const ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
const handleResponse = function() {
  //have we got a response from the server
  if (ajaxRequest.readyState === 4) {
    //did we find the requested resource?
    if (ajaxRequest.status === 200) {
      //  console.log(ajaxRequest.responseText); //testing file
      let data = JSON.parse(ajaxRequest.responseText)
      let ul1 = document.querySelectorAll('.ajax')[0];
      let ul2 = document.querySelectorAll('.ajaxCheck');
      for (let i = 0; i < ul2.length; i++) {
        ul2[i].style.display = 'none';
        console.log(i);
      }
      if (document.querySelectorAll('.ajax')[0]) {
        ul1.innerHTML = displayOutput(data, false);
      } else {
        ul2.innerHTML = displayOutput(data, true);
      }
      //displayOutput_compare(data);
    }
  }
}
```

Specifically the `ajaxCheck` class as it has more than 1.

What am I doing wrong?

here's the HTML for the 2nd class,
it doesn't load any of the data:

```
<ul class="ajaxCheck">
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: "document.getQuerySelector not working". Glancing at your JavaScript, I don't see anything that jumps out. We can't test your code because we would need your HTML. You'll need to post your HTML. Also, a bit more explanation would be nice. What are you trying to do? What exactly isn't working?

Comment: There's no function named `document.getqueryselector`. And your code never calls that function. What's the question about?

Comment: the ajaxCheck isnt working at all, even with the loop. nothing happens

Comment: Instead of using `querySelectorAll` followed by `[0]`, use `querySelector`, it returns the first match.

Comment: apologies let me be more clear: the variable for class: ajax is fine. but for some reason the ajaxCheck one isnt showing any results when run. there is 1 class for ajax and 2 classes for ajaxCheck, both on different pages

Comment: What do you mean by "on different pages"? Javascript can only access the current page.

Comment: `if (document.querySelectorAll('.ajax')[0])` should just be `if(ul1)`.

Comment: oh i see what you mean now, i got it fixed thanks alot!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ul2` is a collection, not a single element. You need to loop over it when setting `innerHTML`, just like you did when setting `style`.

```
if (ul1) {
    ul1.innerHTML = displayOutput(data, false);
} else (
    let output = displayOutput(data, true);
    for (let i = 0; i < ul2.length; i++) {
        ul2[i].innerHTML = output;
    }
}
```